# IE9 GPO Setting "Configure Tracking Protection Lists"

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've just installed IE9 on my workstations and Server in our network. According to technet article

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699401.aspx

There is a GPO setting for IE9 called

"Configure Tracking Protection Lists" located at Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Privacy in the admistrative templates.

I can find all the other IE9 settings in the GPO, but I cannot find this one. Does anyone know if there is an updated template, or if this setting was removed from the RC version of IE9?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Are you editing the GPO with a machine that has IE9 installed? The administrative templates are loaded from the machine editing, which affects which settings you have available. No idea on the status that specific setting, though.

Comment: Yes I am. I can see all the other IE9 related settings, but for whatever reason this one is not there.

Comment: It seems you're correct about the setting not being available anymore: This guy also shows that just that one and 2 others are MIA: http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/03/internet-explorer-9-group-policy-settings/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I'll see if I can do it via Group Preferences. That should be fun, NOT.

Comment: @DanielB keep in mind that machine settings are almost always registry settings. Just because the option is not in GP does not mean the registry setting does not work. You might want to find what the registry setting is and experiment with that.